# Build columns of Yes / No depending on data from another table in mysql

Tags: mysql, select, view

So I have a bunch of tables, each has some sort of data about a user.

```
table 1: first_name, last_name, email
table 2: info_1, info_2, info_3
```

I'm trying to build a SELECT query, which will be used to build a VIEW, where it looks something like this

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, email, has_info_1, has_info_2, has_info_3 FROM tables1, 2 WHERE some condition.
```

But instead of actually grabbing the info_1,2,3 data i just want to check if that data exists in table2, and say Y or N within has_info_1,2,3.

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: `Case when info_1 = 'value' or info_2 = 'Value2' or info_3='value3' then 'Y' else 'N' end as HasInfoInTable2`  But how does talbe 2 relate to table 1?  A cross join here seems too basic as it implies every record in table 2 relates to every record in table 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
SELECT
  Table1.First_Name,
  Table1.Last_Name,
  Table1.Email,
  CASE WHEN Table2.Info_1 IS NULL THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END AS Has_Info_1,
  CASE WHEN Table2.Info_2 IS NULL THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END AS Has_Info_2,
  CASE WHEN Table2.Info_3 IS NULL THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END AS Has_Info_3
FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.Whatever = Table2.Whatever
```

Comment: Ouch, that was simpler than i imagined! Thank You!